# Dúvida JSON PHP

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Eu estou tentando exibir na tela uma estrutura *JSON* que será construída pelo *MySQL*, mas eu gostaria de separar os resultado em grupos de acordo com o nome dos campos que eu definir no select e gostaria de algo como:

```
minha_array
    carro
        carro 1
        carro 2
        carro 3
        carro 4
    imagem
        imagem 1
        imagem 2
        imagem 3
        imagem 4
```

Meu código:

```
<?php

//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select carro, imagem from carros";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray['minha_array']['carro'][] = $row['carro'];
    $emparray['minha_array']['imagem'][] = $row['imagem'];
}

echo json_encode($emparray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Olá Rayann. Prazer em conhecê-lo. Primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda. Cara, ficou show, mas tem como deixar tudo separado, pulando linha tanto nos indices como nos resultados, que nem eu mostrei na pergunta acima e que não interfira na leitura do JSON ?

Comment: Eu construi o array para reproduzir o exemplo que você citou.
Para você ler o json todo identado e com quebra de linha você precisa instalar uma extensão no seu navegador, por exemplo JSONView.

Comment: ok, Obrigado amigo

Comment: @abduzeedo eu editei a resposta com uma constante para o json_encode(), isso deve imprimir o json da forma que você espera.

Comment: Bacana, só uma duvida, como eu faço para ter um indice geral e dentro dele os meus campos, exemplo: array( aqui dentro os campos do json )? Eu editei meu exemplo de como tem de ser o json.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Rayann Nayran. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu já sinalizei sua resposta.